# Im currently trying to create a payment method in android studio ive tried stripe with no luck any ideas

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

I have no idea what this error means, I am new to android studio so would welcome some help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include the error as *text* inside the question, not as an image. It ensures that the question remains useful even if the URL stops working AND allows people to copy the error text to search for solutions. Also, please see these guidelines for creating helpful questions: 
[How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thanks!

Comment: The easier it is to read and understand your question, the best answers you will get.  That transparent window is terrible for readability.  And do not put images of text here, copy paste it directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing parameters of wrong type to the constructur `Card()`

The `expMonth` and `expYear` are integers in your class Card, not strings